# Filling density plot with colours

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I have this `ggplot2` script:

```
require(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(extrafont)
font_import(pattern = 'Arch') 
font_import(pattern = 'Akk') 

fileName = paste("/ex_spectra.csv", sep = "") # data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gs1hwv3xjnlhb7z/ex_spectra.csv?dl=0
mydata = read.csv(fileName,sep=",", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
dataM = melt(mydata,c("x"))

my_palette = c(brewer.pal(5, "Set1")[c(1,2,3,4,5)])

ggplot(data=dataM, aes(x= x, y=value, colour=variable, fill = variable, size = variable)) +
geom_line(alpha = .75) +

scale_colour_manual(breaks=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), values=my_palette) +
scale_size_manual(breaks=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), values=c(0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7)) +

theme(plot.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), #panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
axis.line = element_blank(),
legend.key = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank()) +
scale_y_continuous("y", expand=c(0,0)) + 
scale_x_continuous("x", expand=c(0,0)) +

theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.3, face="bold", size=12, colour = "grey50", family="AkkuratPro-Regular")) + 

theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5, face="bold", size=12, colour = "grey50", family="AkkuratPro-Regular")) +

theme(legend.position = "right", axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9, angle = 0, vjust = 0.25 , hjust = 1, colour = "grey50", family="AkkuratLightPro-Regular")
  ,axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9, angle = 0, hjust = 1, colour = "grey50", family="AkkuratLightPro-Regular"))
```

Which produces this plot:

[image]

Now, I'd like to fill the density curves with their corresponding colours (at, say, 25% alpha). Isn't `fill = variable` the usual way to do this?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data.

Comment: You need `geom_area`

Comment: This seems to work just fine: `ggplot(data.frame(x=runif(100), g=rep(c("a","b"), each=50))) + geom_density(aes(x=x, fill=g), alpha=.25)`. Please define all the variables in your code to make the example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r?sort=frequent&pageSize=15)

Comment: Your plot isn't a density plot. It's a line plot (`geom_line`) where the line goes through each (x,y) point (x=Eigenvalues, y=value). `geom_line` doesn't recognize a fill aesthetic, since there's nothing to fill from geom_line's point of view. As @zx8754 mentioned, use `geom_area` to fill in the line plots. Also, you don't need a size aesthetic if you want all the linewidths to be the same. Just add `size=0.7` or `lwd=0.7` in `geom_line`

Comment: Thanks so much, indeed, it's not a density plot per say (although it plots density data, built in a python script). I updated the question with a dataset, it should become clearer.

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is needlessly complex if you're just concerned about filling the area under the line.

Here's a simple example of filling the area under the lines of your data using `geom_area` and your sample data.

```
ggplot(data=dataM, aes(x= x, y=value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_area(alpha = .75, position="identity")
```

which returns

[image]

Comment: Cool, almost what I was looking for. In fact, I'd need the lines as well, while keeping the same legend. If it's not really possible, your current answer is really close enough. Thanks!

Comment: If you want the lines as well, just add the `geom_line` back in: `+ geom_line(aes(color=variable))`